# Nginx Rewrite rule not working with subdomain

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect URLs like this:

```
  http://example.com/tmcontent/comprehension/el_semenario.mp3
```

to this:

```
  http://static.example.com/tmcontent/comprehension/el_semenario.mp3
```

Currently I am doing this

```
  rewrite /(tmcontent.*)$  http://static.example.com/$1 redirect;
```

But sadly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /tmcontent {
    return 301 http://static.example.com/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But no redirection :(